Flask: url_for with path parameter and query parameter
I have a base.html where all my other pages extend from. In the base.html I want different links with the possibility to add different query parameters to the page I'm currently at.
That is easy with:
url_for(request.endpoint, querypara=value)

I know that I can just add the path parameter also like this:
url_for(request.endpoint, pathpara=value, querypara=value)

But my problem is, that I have different pages with different path parameters.
So page1, for example, would need:
url_for(request.endpoint, pathpara1=value, querypara=value)

page2:
url_for(request.endpoint, pathpara2=value, querypara=value)

And maybe page3 don't need any path parameter:
url_for(request.endpoint, querypara=value)

Is there a way to add both (or just the query) but still be flexible so I don't have to write different Jinja code for every page with path parameters.
I already know how to work around it without the base.html and just not extending every page of it. But I am interested if anyone has a smart solution for it.

Found a way to do it!
The solution was to combine the following three:

request.args (the query arguments that the request received)
request.views (the path arguments that we received)
possible new arguments

request.args and request.views each provide a dictionary.
I wrote a little function that combined all three:
def combine_view_args(*args):
    dic = {}
    for arg in args:
        dic.update(arg)
    return dic

We give the new possible arguments as a dictionary aswell.
To access the function in Jinja we need to add it in the context_processor
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    return dict(combine_view_args=combine_view_args)

and so we can use all of that in the url_for in the end
<a href="{{url_for(request.endpoint, **combine_view_args(request.args,request.view_args,{'newArgument':'value'}) )}}">Value</a>
            

